# Find $I(a,n)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos{(ax)}}{x^n} \mathop{dx}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I am tasked to find $$I(a,n)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos{(ax)}}{x^n} \mathop{dx}$$
Where $0<n<1$.  I tried to add $e^{-tx}$ and differentiate wrt $t$, but this is too messy.  Can someone help guide me?  I am looking for a short solution.

Comment: https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.9#E6


enjoy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $u=ax$ then you can easily isolate the $a$ in the intgeral:
$$I(a,n)=a^{n-1} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos{u}}{u^n} \; du$$
If you recognize this as the [Mellin transform](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MellinTransform.html) of $\cos{u}$, then you can express your integral as:

$$I(a,n)=a^{n-1} \int_0^{\infty} \cos{u}\cdot u^{(1-n)-1} \; du = a^{n-1} \Gamma(1-n) \cos{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\left(1-n\right)\right)}$$
$$\boxed{I(a,n)=a^{n-1} \Gamma(1-n) \sin{\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)}}$$
Which converges for $0<\Re(n)<1$

Comment: @Integrand Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A little late, but nevertheless, I´ll live my answer.

Consider :
$$\Gamma(n)=x^{n}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-xt}t^{n-1}dt $$

Now $$\Gamma(n)I(a,n)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos(ax)\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-xt}t^{n-1}dt dx$$

Interchanging the order of integration we get:

$$\Gamma(n)I(a,n)=\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{n-1} \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-xt}\cos(ax)dx dt$$

$$\Gamma(n)I(a,n)=\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{n-1}\color{red} {\frac{t}{a^{2}+t^{2}}}   dt $$

$$\Gamma(n)I(a,n)=\frac{1}{a^{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty} {\frac{t^n}{1+\left(\frac{t}{a}\right)^{2}}}   dt $$

Now make the folowing substitution $u=\left(\frac{t}{a}\right)^{2}$ to get:
$$\Gamma(n)I(a,n)=\frac{a^{n-1}}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}{1+u}du $$

$$\Rightarrow\Gamma(n)I(a,n)=\frac{a^{n-1}}{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}{2}+1\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1-n}{2}\right)$$

Leading to:

$$I(a,n)=\frac{a^{n-1}}{2}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}{2}+1\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1-n}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(n)}$$

And as noted by @Nanayajitzuki in the comments below, we can apply Euler´s reflection formula for the Gamma function, which gives us:

$$\boxed{I(a,n)=\frac{a^{n-1}}{2}\frac{\pi}{\Gamma(n)\cos(\frac{n \pi }{2})}}$$

Comment: with reflection formula, we may have $$\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}{2}+1\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1-n}{2}\right)}{2\Gamma(n)} = \frac{\pi}{2\Gamma(n)\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)} = \Gamma(1-n)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)$$